# Replaced drivers side seat 2009 chevy malibu, new seat does not have side airbag

Tags: chevrolet, malibu, seat, supplemental-restraint-system

I have a 2009 chevy malibu with the collapsed driver seat. I replaced the seat with a very similar seat from a 2008 chevy malibu, it does not have the side airbag like the previous seat did so the yellow side air bag connector has nothing to hook it in. The seat fits great, so I solved that problem. I need a solution to the yellow side air bag connector so the air bag light goes out. I have the female connector off my old seat. Is there a resistor I can put into the connector?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to order an airbag emulator so assuming that works the light will go out. fingers crossed.